# Receive RTP Stream with MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, vlc

I have problem with MobileVLCKit. I want to receive with my iOS app a live stream from my computer, which is hosted by VLC. But when I want to connect, I get an error, which says, that it can't connect. I can ping my iPhone and all works perfekt except of VLC.

Here is the code snippet of my app:

```
self.mediaplayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];
self.mediaplayer.delegate = self;
self.mediaplayer.drawable = self.uvCamera;
NSURL *urlTest = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streams.videolan.org/streams/mp4/Mr_MrsSmith-h264_aac.mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.1.167:8080/"];
self.mediaplayer.media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:url];
[self.mediaplayer play];
```

When I use the urlTest for the stream, it works perfekt, but the local IP does not work.
can someone help me?

Comment: not familiar with this subject... but the urlTest has a file but not the url!

Comment: The interesting question for me would be: does this local URL play with VLC on another Mac OR PC on the same network? (a machine different from the streamer) additionally, do you get any error messages?